# Is there a lint tool to check the code against the Dart style guide?

Tags: dart

I would like to write code that conforms to the Dart style guide. Therefore I am curios, whether there is any automatic way to check the coding style for Dart.

Do you know about any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Dart 1.13 (currently release candidate) you can enable lint checks, strong mode and other features by adding an `.analysis_options` file to your Dart project (the folder with the `pubspec.yaml` file)

```
analyzer:
  strong-mode: true
  exclude:
  - test/data/**
  language:
    enableSuperMixins: true
linter:
  rules:
    # see http://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/
    - always_declare_return_types
    - always_specify_types
    - camel_case_types
    - constant_identifier_names
    - empty_constructor_bodies
    - implementation_imports
    - library_names
    - library_prefixes
    - non_constant_identifier_names
    - one_member_abstracts
    - package_api_docs
    - package_prefixed_library_names
    - slash_for_doc_comments
    - super_goes_last
    - type_init_formals
#    - unnecessary_brace_in_string_interp
    - unnecessary_getters_setters
    - package_names
```

The available lint rules are listed in http://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/

See also

- https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/analysis-options
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/linter

Answer (score 4):

There is an open issue you can star to vote for adding the feature to Dart Editor:

https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=2059